# how to validate amount text value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

i am facing small issue that how to validate amount value in uitextfiled. i have an limit of amount text filed should be greater than Rs.10 and range between value is Rs.99999. incase user enter invalid amount like Rs.01,02,04,09 this types of number should be avoided

i just done simple method to call my function as :

```
 if ([amount.text length]>=2 && [amount.text length]<=5) {

}else{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the code below:

```
if ([amount.text doubleValue]>=10 && [amount.text doubleValue]<99999){

}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really do the parsing using [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html). It is highly configurable and says easily, if the input is corrupted. Beside this it has a `minimum` and `maximum` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int val = amount.text.integerValue
if (val > 10 && val < 99999){

}
else{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Here you have full control of what will be displayed in the text field. Since the method returns a `BOOL` value you can accept the replacement string (by returning `YES`) if it satisfies your requirements or keep the old text by returning `NO`.

Don't forget to assign the delegate to the `UITextField` in order for this method to be called.

For more information check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

**EDIT:**

Possible solution:

1. If the textfield should only take numerical characters, you should set the keyboard type as:

   `textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;`
2. In the implementation of the above method you could write:

   `NSInteger value = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].integerValue;
   if (value >=10 && value <= 99999){
       return YES;
   }else{
       // inform the user the input is invalid
       return NO;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to restrict the user entering single no and 6 digits no.

**Note:** Use KeyboardType as UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length >= 5 && range.length < 2)
    {
        return NO; //Not allowing the user to enter single character or greater than 5 characters
    }
    else
    {
    return YES;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you...!